# keras's model.fit() is not consistent with model.evaluate()

Tags: python, keras

I have a set of 32 chairs and 32 lamps which form one training set. I ran them through a simple CNN in Keras whose goal was to discriminate chairs from lamps.
When calling model.fit(), I achieve accuracy close to 1.0 according to the printout. After training, however, model.evaluate() on the training data results in an accuracy of ~0.5.

Here's my code:

```
# train_tensors, train_labels contain training data
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=5,
                 kernel_size=[4, 4],
                 strides=2,
                 padding='same',
                 input_shape=[225, 225, 3]))
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=10,
                 kernel_size=[4, 4],
                 strides=2,
                 padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNorm(axis=3))  # imported BatchNormalization as BatchNorm
model.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_tensors, train_labels, batch_size=8, epochs=5, shuffle=True)

metrics = model.evaluate(train_tensors, train_labels)
print('')
print(np.ravel(model.predict(train_tensors)))
print('training data results: ')
for i in range(len(model.metrics_names)):
    print(str(model.metrics_names[i]) + ": " + str(metrics[i]))
```

`train_tensors` was used for both model.fit() and model.evaluate(). The printout was:

```
Epoch 1/5
 8/64 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6927 - acc: 0.5000
16/64 [======>.......................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.1480 - acc: 0.5000
24/64 [==========>...................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.8194 - acc: 0.6667
40/64 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5205 - acc: 0.8000
56/64 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4896 - acc: 0.8036
64/64 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.4504 - acc: 0.8125     
Epoch 2/5
 8/64 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0082 - acc: 1.0000
24/64 [==========>...................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0391 - acc: 1.0000
40/64 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0444 - acc: 0.9750
56/64 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0392 - acc: 0.9821
64/64 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0382 - acc: 0.9844     
Epoch 3/5
 8/64 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4.8843e-04 - acc: 1.0000
24/64 [==========>...................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.5668e-04 - acc: 1.0000
40/64 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 6.1193e-04 - acc: 1.0000
56/64 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0096 - acc: 1.0000    
64/64 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0128 - acc: 1.0000     
Epoch 4/5
 8/64 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 9.2490e-04 - acc: 1.0000
24/64 [==========>...................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 9.6854e-04 - acc: 1.0000
40/64 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 9.6813e-04 - acc: 1.0000
56/64 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.5456e-04 - acc: 1.0000
64/64 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 8.3200e-04 - acc: 1.0000     
Epoch 5/5
 8/64 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4.2928e-04 - acc: 1.0000
24/64 [==========>...................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0044 - acc: 1.0000    
40/64 [=================>............] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0027 - acc: 1.0000
56/64 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0026 - acc: 1.0000
64/64 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0024 - acc: 1.0000     
32/64 [==============>...............] - ETA: 0s
64/64 [==============================] - 0s     

[  2.20039312e-21   3.70743738e-15   7.76885543e-08   3.38629164e-20
   1.26636347e-14   8.46270983e-23   4.83105518e-24   1.63172146e-07
   3.59334761e-28   7.74249325e-20   6.30969798e-28   2.79597981e-12
   1.17927814e-21   3.84340554e-01   3.83124183e-23   4.88756598e-07
   8.28199488e-27   3.89127730e-16   7.77586222e-32   2.96250031e-21
   1.51558620e-22   3.26927439e-12   1.96537564e-20   2.68915438e-16
   2.90332289e-17   1.78180949e-03   6.45235020e-23   2.82894642e-25
   9.87989724e-01   5.52072190e-02   6.61221920e-31   6.48611497e-29
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.91474397e-38
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   1.56358186e-38   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
training data results: 
loss: 7.17852215999
acc: 0.515625
```

There's a huge discrepancy between the accuracy during model.fit() and the accuracy from model.evaluate(), which is 0.515625. Why might this be?

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the batchnorm - could you do a test without the `BatchNormalization` layer?

Comment: @y300 I think you're right, removing BatchNormalization makes the two tests equal. So it seems that `model.evaluate()` (as well as `model.predict()`) don't apply BatchNormalization in my model.

Comment: That's not quite correct, the issue is kind of suble. See my answer for a fuller response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `BatchNormalization` layer. As you've noted in your comment, removing the layer makes the model work. The issue here is that batchnorm works differently when training vs when testing. At train time, it uses statistics computed on a per batch basis. As testing time, it uses statistics (mean/stdev) computed over the whole run of the training, as a running mean of the whole training set. Since your training is so short, the statistics have not been accurately completed in all likelihood.

You could either (a) remove the batchnorm layer, as I mentioned in a comment which seems to work. Or (b) increase the rate at which the moving mean/std is computed, by adjusting the parameter `momentum` in the batchnorm layer to a lower value. Try momentum in the range `[0.5-0.95]`

Comment: thanks, this makes more sense. I later tried with MNIST (with a much larger test set) and my implementation did better.

Comment: thanks, I removed the BatchNormalization layers from the model, and both Acuracies match in value now.